# Solving $|3x-1|+|2x-3|-|x+5|<2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Solve:  $|3x-1|+|2x-3|-|x+5|<2$

Ive tried bringing $|x+5|$ to the L.H side of the inequality and then squaring both sides but I would still be left with 3 absolute values. I could try separating into cases but they would be endless. Can anyone help me in solving the inequality?

Comment: Are you able to utilize Cartesian graphing to solve the inequality?

Comment: @Decaf-Math I'm not sure but I would love to see that method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remember that $$|x+a| = \begin{cases}x+a & \text{if } x \ge -a \\ -(x+a) &\text{if } x<-a \end{cases}$$

So,

$$|3x-1|+|2x-3|-|x+5|= \begin{cases}-(3x-1)-(2x-3)+(x+5) &  \text{if } x<-5 \\-(3x-1)-(2x-3)-(x+5) & \text{if } -5\le x<\frac 13 \\ (3x-1)-(2x-3)-(x+5) & \text{if } \frac13\le x<\frac 32 \\ (3x-1)+(2x-3)-(x+5) & \text{if } x\ge\frac32\end{cases}$$

Could you proceed from here?

Comment: So basically just see the look for intervals and see how the absolute values behave in those intervals

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 4):

"I would love to see that [graphing] method"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The left side is a piecewise linear function where there is an abrupt change in slope at $1/3$, $3/2$, and $-5$. I would plot the left side at those three points. Then connect segments with straight lines. Then work out the far left and far right ray's slopes, and proceed from there.

Comment: but how would I solve it algebraically?